# two for loop in python fileinput

Tags: python, for-loop, mysql-python

```
cur = mysqlcon.cursor()
sql_select_query = """select name,AES_DECRYPT(passwd, 'hardpass') as passwd from fullusers WHERE id = %s"""
# set variable in query
cur.execute(sql_select_query, (iduser,))
myresult = cur.fetchone()
nameuser = myresult['name']
passuser = myresult['passwd']
psuser = str(passuser,'utf-8')

if mysqlcon:
    print ("Connected Successfully")
else:
    print ("Connection Not Established")

query = """select * from v_ips WHERE uid = %s"""
cur.execute(query, (iduser,))
data = cur.fetchall()
file_name = '/usr/local/etc/3proxy.cfg'
for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_name,inplace=1):
    if 'allow login,'+ nameuser +'' in line:
        for x in data:
            line = line.rstrip()
            line = line.replace(line, line+'\rproxy -n -a -p8989 -i'+ x['ip'] +' -e'+ x['ip'] +'')
```

It is necessary to add several lines from the database to the file after a certain word, when such a structure is as above, all the data in the file simply disappears, maybe I'm doing something wrong?

```
for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_name,inplace=1):
    if 'allow login,'+ nameuser +'' in line:
                line = line.rstrip()
        for x in data:
            line = line.replace(line, line+'\rproxy -n -a -p8989 -i'+ x['ip'] +' -e'+ x['ip'] +'')
```

such a structure also deletes all data in the file, swapping the loop occurs just as simply deleting all data

Comment: Your use of `line.replace` in the loop over `data` seems strange to me: why don't you just add the new parts to `line`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the `fileinput` library so this might not be "best practice" by any means, however I got it working at least.

With the test file `test_file.txt` containing this:

```
test
test
no
no
test
no
```

and with the following code:

```py
import fileinput

file_name = "test_file.txt"
for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_name,inplace=1):
    if 'test' in line:
        print(line.replace(line,"this line has officially been tested"))
    else:
        print(line, end="")
```

I got the following result:

```
this line has officially been tested
this line has officially been tested
no
no
this line has officially been tested
no
```

For some reason using `print` within the `FileInput` block of code prints to the file not stdout.

Additionally it is recommended to use context managers whenever operating on files.

Example:

```py
import fileinput

file_name = "test_file.txt"

with fileinput.FileInput(file_name,inplace=1) as file:
    for line in file:
        if 'test' in line:
            print(line.replace(line,"this line has officially been tested"))
        else:
            print(line, end="")
```

Comment: If `inplace` is truthy then `sys.stdout` is redirected to the input stream - this is why `print` writes to the file.